# OpenXML converting .docx to .doc

Tags: vb.net, openxml, openxml-sdk, docx, .doc

I've successfully implemented OpenXML that takes the bookmarks within a document and replaces them. Unfortunately it only works with .docx and from what I understand .doc is not compatible with the OpenXML format.

So, what I'm wondering is if I can take that `WordprocessingDocument` and convert it to a .doc when users try and download it. Is that possible? If so anyone know how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converting from DOCX to DOC with Open XML SDK 2.0 is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Either use a third party library, like Aspose.Words. Or you need to use Microsoft Interop services.

This is sample C# code:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application wordApplication = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document wordDocument = wordApplication.Documents.Open(opath);
wordDocument.SaveAs("BLUH.DOC",  WdSaveFormat.wdFormatDocument);

((Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word._Document)wordDocument).Close(); // cast necessary
((Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word._Application)wordApplication).Quit(); // cast necessary
```

Take a look at these pages:

[FileConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms263819%28v=office.11%29)

[SaveFormat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.wdsaveformat%28v=office.11%29.aspx)

[SaveAs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word._document.saveas%28v=office.11%29.aspx)

Comment: And if I don't have Microsoft Word, Aspose.Words then?

Comment: AsposeWords costs quite a bit, you might find a cheaper/free third-party library. Just want to reaffirm that you cannot do this with OpenXML SDK.

Comment: So, caught between a rock and hard place then?

Comment: More or less. There is always an option to let the user download a free   compatibility pack that lets them view docx files on Microsoft Office 2003 platform.

Comment: Except we're dealing with users that are less than tech savvy. So, we don't want them to call tech support more than they already are.

Comment: How about letting them downloads PDF's instead? Most users have PDF readers (I think), and there are a lot of libraries (should be quite a few free), that convert docx to pdf.

Comment: Was actually just suggested to look into that. Have any recommendations?

Comment: what language you want to use? VB?

Comment: VB, but never mind. Coworker says that format will not work. So right now I'm just trying to figure out how to save out WordprocessingDocument. Not sure how to do that.

Comment: You can use JODConverter (a service wrapper for OpenOffice/LibreOffice) to convert from docx to doc